# Zsh: make single file selection smart, stylish, and functionally correct (highlights, completions below cursor, etc)

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete, zle

I would like to have a near-flawless "single file selector" with zsh. So far I haven't seen one in questions as they tend to focus on zle settings for one's command line. Let's say we are writing a single file selector that prompts user to provide a single file in some directory. Below is my beginning code that works but needs multiple improvements:

1. Highlight: current menu selection item should be highlighted with reverse-video.
2. Order: the possible file completions should be shown below the prompt.
3. Prompt stepping: Prompt shouldn't step below after printing possible options above. This is related to 2.
4. Only one: Tab complete only first item, as we are asking for only 1 file name from user, not multiple. (This is what I mean by "functionally correct")
5. Size: If there are more possible completions than can fit below the prompt, that case is handled elegantly. Assume alternate screen, and no screen movement or scrolling available.
6. Bonus: If you could think of yet another nice feature to have for a single file selector, feel free to add. Though it would be nice to have it in a separate listing or with comments to identify how to remove your that from solution for 1-5 above.

Note: The answer would be self-contained zsh code. It wouldn't ask user to edit .zshrc or install some zsh extension/plugin/framework/library.

Create a file `foofiles.zsh` in a temp directory, chmod and run it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt extendedglob
setopt globcomplete
setopt nomenucomplete

mkdir ./foo 2>/dev/null
cd ./foo
touch abcd ebcf gbch ijkl mnop qrst unov wxyz
cd ..

function foofileselector {
    cd ./foo/
    local curcontext=foofileselector:::
    vared -p "Select file: " -c foofile;
    cd ..
}

function _foofileselector {
    _files -W ./foo/
}

zstyle ':completion:foofileselector:*:' insert-tab false completer _foofileselector

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

foofileselector
[[ -z $foofile ]] && foofile="NIL"
echo "You selected: $foofile"

rm -rf ./foo/
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: foofiles.zsh file completion run]

This is close ([zim](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw)'s file completion):
[image: zim file completion run]

Comment: You’re asking 6 different questions in one post. You’re more likely to get answers if you ask them in separate posts.

Comment: Depends on how you read the question, it is can be understood as one question: how to build a single file completion prompt with all bells and whistles. Having it in one place will help others also understand how to solve a similar problem like this. I can create 5 other questions and point them here, though closing this will be a bad idea for people trying to learn how to build a completion with bells and whistles and approach a similar problem.

Comment: “Having it in one place will help others also understand how to solve a similar problem like this.” That’s not what Stack Exchange is for. Questions are encouraged to be as minimal as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: However, once you have all the info you need, feel free to publish the code on GitHub or write a blog post about it.

Comment: @MarlonRichert You misread the description of the page you point. The "minimal" word there is used for code. And the 20ish lines of code I provide is pretty minimal. I think the question I pose is pretty minimal in scope, and many people will benefit from coming here if someone answers it. Then you can write a blog on how stackexchange is more dynamic than you thought ;)